# How to schedule in Windows shutdown of application?

Tags: windows, schedule

In Windows XP are scheduled tasks. With them possible schedule to run some application.
I didn't found, but may be possible to shutdown some application by schedule?
Thanks.

Comment: Do you have control over the application? If you do, it can be done through the application itself, otherwise, this probably belongs on SuperUser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make batch file (for ex.: shutdown_application.bat) with command

```
c:\windows\system32\taskkill.exe -IM notepad.exe
```

where `notepad.exe` is your appliction exe name.

Now add shedule with this batch file.